# How do I update the value in ACE editor: javascript

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

`setValue` presumably just sets the value of the editor. How about when I have some `diff` and what i want is some method that just adds the diff to the current value? Is there some `API` for this?

Comment: You'd probably have to implement this yourself. ```getValue``` and then add the diff yourself. Then ```setValue```

Comment: how? I'd have to be able to do something like setValueAtSomePosition in which case i wont need to getValue since I know the diff and the position. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
editor.session.insert({row, column}, text)
editor.session.remove({start: {row, column}, end:  {row, column}})
editor.session.doc.replace(range, text)
```

to apply each edit individually, or you can get value of the editor modify the string, and call `setSalue` with the modified string.

see https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/lib/ace/document.js#L522

Answer (score 0):

You can update the value of the editor by getting the session and then inserting into the particular position by getting the row and column positions of the editor.

Example:

If the editor now contains "select"

```
var text = "abc";
var pos = editor.selection.getCursor();
var session = editor.session;

session.insert({
row: session.getLength(), // or you can use "pos.row"
column: pos.column,
}, " " + text + " ");
```

The editor will now have : "select abc "

This will directly update the value at the editor.